# What are the effects of self-inductance in a DC armature?

Tags: dc-motor, back-emf, brushed-dc-motor, self-induction

So, I just stopped to think that, for the armature coils, the current passing through them varies with time due to commutation.

The voltage applied to different conductors in the armature varies abruptly, and I'd expect it to respond similarly to an inductor fed with a square wave voltage, presenting an impedance that's greater than it's DC resistance (and also distorting the current wave form a lot).

So, to test that, I fed only the armature of a DC motor,while leaving the field winding open.

I had to use a resistance in series to limit the current, it was a 21.5 ohm resistance.

With the armature stationary, the current was 950 mA DC. Then I wound string on its axis and spun it the fastest I could, the current dropped by 100 mA at peak speed.

Considering the series resistance and the voltage, this means the armature impedance rose from 4.6 ohms while stationary to 7.7 ohms while spinning.

I also tested doing it with the field winding shorted, it didn't make any difference.

Also, It's interesting to note that, while there's no DC voltage being induced on the field winding, there is a high frequency AC voltage with considerable magnitude being induced on it.

My multimeter measured up to 7 V RMS induced in the field winding, with a peak frequency of 1.5 kHz when I spun the axis the fastest I could with the string (which I consider to be probably under 2000 rpm, this isn't a small motor).

Anyway, it looks like self-inductance in the armature is reducing the DC current on itself a lot.

I also tried to measure AC current on the armature while spinning it, but the greatest value I got was a mere 10 mA in peak speed, and obviously zero while it was stationary.

Anyway: How do I take this in account?

Previously I considered that the armature total impedance depended only on its resistance and the back-emf from the main field, but seems like there's also self-inductance here.

Comment: Don't forget the remanent magnetism in the field. Just reducing the field current to zero doesn't reduce the field to zero.

Comment: @KevinWhite It's too weak to cause that much reduction in the current. I measured the induced voltage from the remanent field on the armature, it reached 0.6 V at peak speed. It would reduce the current by 23 mA by itself.

Comment: *DC voltage being induced on the field winding* - that would be a miracle.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, I just said there's none. I was reaffirming that.

Comment: You said (above in your post): *Also, It's interesting to note that, while there's DC voltage being induced on the field winding* so no, you didn't just say there is none.

Comment: @Andyaka Oh sorry, there should be a 'no' there (even why the phrase doesn't make much sense without it).